# Prompt user to download file via AJAX form submission

Tags: 8, files

I have a file that is generated when an AJAX button is clicked. I want to immediately have a file download prompt come up. The file is being generated and has the correct data in the file. I just don't know how to force the download prompt to come up.

**Edit#1**

I have updated the `generateCSV()` code to include:

```
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($path . $filename);
$response->setContentDisposition(
  ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
  $filename
);

$form_state->setResponse($response);
```

This is not invoking a download.

**AJAX Button**

```
$form['comp_card_dl'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => $this->t('Download'),
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::generateCSV',
    'progress' => [
      'type' => 'throbber',
    ],
  ],
  '#name' => 'comp_card_download',
];
```

**CSV File Creation**

```
public function generateCSV($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $trigger = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
  if ($trigger['#name'] == 'gift_card_download') {
    $filename = $form['#gift_card_filename'];
    $data = $form['#gift_card_data'];
  }
  else if ($trigger['#name'] == 'comp_card_download') {
    $filename = $form['#comp_card_filename'];
    $data = $form['#comp_card_data'];
  }

  $path = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath(file_default_scheme() . "://") . '/';
  $csv = fopen($path . $filename, 'w');

  foreach ($data as $id => $value) {
    array_unshift($value, $id);
    fputcsv($csv, $value);
  }

  fclose($csv);

  $response = new BinaryFileResponse($path . $filename);
  $response->setContentDisposition(
    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    $filename
  );

  $form_state->setResponse($response);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download file upon submitting a form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245451/how-to-download-file-upon-submitting-a-form)

Comment: I am testing out their suggestion from that post. I'll update the post with results.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, its is not working by just jQuery but working by JavaScript click on a link.

First you need a html element with the download attribute

```
<a id="download-csv" target="_blank" href="" download="file.csv"></a>
```

Write an a js code to add `href` and then a javascript to click the element by its ID.

```
  $.fn.ajaxDownlaodHistory = function($path) {
    $("#download-csv").attr('href', window.location.origin + '/' + $path);
    document.getElementById("download-csv").click();
  };
```

In you PHP code, I consider you create your file successfully. Then you need to InvokeCommand that calls the recent js function created.

```
// Response to download the file directly
$response = new AjaxResponse();
$response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, "ajaxDownlaodHistory", [$path]));
return $response;
```

You need to import

> use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
>
> use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand;