# How to return an XLS file to download on form submit

Tags: 8, forms

I am trying to create an XLS file and send it to the browser on a form submit but I cannot figure out how to do it. I am using XLS Serialization module but I'm open to all other suggestions. With this module I successfully created some views with XLS Export feature. But now I have a form and the excel file should be created on form submit depending on the submitted data.

I created the following code but if I send the form, I get no excel file to download:

```php
class MyForm extends FormBase {
  private SerializerInterface $serializer;

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static($container->get('serializer'));
  }

  public function __construct(SerializerInterface $serializer) {
    $this->serializer = $serializer;
  }

  // Removed the buildForm() etc for simplicity

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = (new StreamedResponse(function () use ($selected_values) {
      $this->serializer->serialize([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], 'xlsx');
    }))->send();

    $form_state->setResponse($response);
  }
}
```

Comment: "didn't work" ? Not sure what that means exactly ... The only weird thing I can see is the ->send(), but you left out some code and you don't say what the error or problem is.

Comment: it means when I send the form, I don't get an excel file to download

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you need a serializer for xls(x), I used https://www.drupal.org/project/xls_serialization

The following example code should deliver what you need:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  $filename = "random_file_" . rand() . ".xlsx";

  $response = new StreamedResponse(function () use ($values) {
    echo $this->serializer->serialize([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], 'xlsx');
  });
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
  $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');

  $form_state->setResponse($response);
}
```

I tried that with the XLS encoder provided https://www.drupal.org/project/xls_serialization and it worked.

Good luck!

References:

- https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-uploads/file-streaming#codeblock-b856bd1a43
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/245460/57183
- https://evertpot.com/222/
- https://www.drupal.org/project/xls_serialization

Comment: Thank you, I worked out a working solution. But with a bit different and simpler callback function in StreamedResponse. Would you mind if I update your code?

Comment: If it's the same approach, yes, please do. Otherwise, this question needs a different answer than mine. Curious in any case! The callback code I wrote in there was based off of your question, perhaps you can update the question and then I can update my answer.

Comment: Updated the code with the one worked for me. Please check my changes: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/308007/revisions If you want you can still rollback to your version. Thanks.

Comment: So, all you needed was the headers' part to get your code working, right?

Comment: Not only the headers. I also added `echo` to the StreamedResponse callback, and removed the `send()` method that I used at the beginning.